# Sonar analyse source step : JavaSourceImporter

Tags: code-analysis, sonarqube

I was wondering what the step " Sensor JavaSourceImporter..." means while analyzing source using command : sonar-runner ?

Actually, I began an analyze but it's now blocked at this step for the last 10minutes !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Sensor JavaSourceImporter..." is a phase during which Sonar reads the source files and stores them in the database.

This step can last quite some time, depending on:

- the size of your code base,
- the distance between the Sonar batch (which does the analysis) and the database (where the sources are pushed). If those 2 parts run on different servers, their location on the network can have significant performance impacts.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answer ! that the kind of answer I was looking for :)